# Scoring strategy of sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV for LatentDirichletAllocation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, lda

I am trying to apply GridSearchCV on the LatentDirichletAllocation using the sklearn library.

### Current pipeline looks like so:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer='word',       
                         min_df=10,                      
                         stop_words='english',           
                         lowercase=True,                 
                         token_pattern='[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}'
                        )

data_vectorized = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc_clean) #where doc_clean is processed text.

lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components =number_of_topics,
                                    max_iter=10,            
                                    learning_method='online',   
                                    random_state=100,       
                                    batch_size=128,         
                                    evaluate_every = -1,    
                                    n_jobs = -1,            
                                    )

search_params = {'n_components': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30], 'learning_decay': [.5, .7, .9]}
model = GridSearchCV(lda_model, param_grid=search_params)
model.fit(data_vectorized)
```

Current the GridSearchCV uses the approximate log-likelihood as score to determine which is the best model. What I would like to do is to change my scoring method to be based on the [*approximate perplexity*](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html#sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.perplexity) of the model instead.

According to sklearn's [documentation of GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html), there is a scoring argument that I can use. However, I do not know how to apply perplexity as a scoring method, and I cannot find any examples online of people applying it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`GridSearchCV` on its default will use the `score()` function of final estimator in the pipeline.

`make_scorer` can be used here, but for calculating perplexity you will need other data from the fitted model as well, which could be a little complex to provide through `make_scorer`.

You can make a wrapper over your LDA here and in which you can re-implement the `score()` function to return `perplexity`. Something along the lines:

```
class MyLDAWithPerplexityScorer(LatentDirichletAllocation):

    def score(self, X, y=None):

        # You can change the options passed to perplexity here
        score = super(MyLDAWithPerplexityScorer, self).perplexity(X, sub_sampling=False)

        # Since perplexity is lower for better, so we do negative
        return -1*score
```

And then can use this in place of `LatentDirichletAllocation` in your code like:

```
...
...
...
lda_model = MyLDAWithPerplexityScorer(n_components =number_of_topics,
                                ....
                                ....   
                                n_jobs = -1,            
                                )
...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The score and perplexity parameters seem to be buggy and to be dependent on the number of topics. Therefore the results in grid will give you the lowest number of topics

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/6777)